# Different image not getting picked up in HTML5

Tags: html

While trying to use different size images in same img tag, only the first image is picked up. The remaining images are not picked up on different display size device.

Here is the code that I am trying with.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="image_1.jpg" sourceset="image_2.jpg 2x, image_3.jpg 6.5x" alt="Image">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error.

Change attribute name `sourceset` to `srcset`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misspelled `srcset`. Try as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="image_1.jpg" srcset="image_2.jpg 2x, image_3.jpg 6.5x" alt="Image">
</body>
</html>
```